# Can I make Google Drive available on my home network as a network drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Can I create a connection on one computer or device that exposes my drive to the rest of my network as a network shared drive?

My specific use case is that I have an older scanner that is connected to my wife that scans files and can send them to an email address, or to a network shared location. I’m trying to get it to send files directly to my Google drive though. Is there any way I can have computer connect to drive that lets the rest of the network see it as a shared drive?

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive integration into Windows means that there will be **some** folder that acts as the Google Drive drop folder.

That folder, typically under your **Documents** folder can be **Shared**:

- Right-click
- Properties
- Sharing tab
- Click **Advanced Sharing**
- Check **Share this folder**
- Click **Permissions**
- Grant **Everyone** the **Change** permission

Good question, totally fits StackOverflow, and definitely shouldn't be closed.

Comment: What does the folder then look like to the rest of my network? Ie. how do I map from another device to that shared folder?

Comment: Once you have the folder shared on your network, it behaves the same as any other folder you share on your network. From your wife's computer, you browse to your computer, find the shared folder, right click, and select **Map network drive**. (I assumed you already knew how to map network drives; that's why i didn't explain that part).